# jquery datatable doesn't sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable that is populated by server side ajax.  Supposedly, datatables are supposed to be sortable by default without having to add any parameters.  Mine isn't.  The sort arrows show up in the column headers and clicking on them flips the arrow but nothing gets sorted.

Here's the datatable definition:

```
$('#appPotTable').DataTable({
    "ordering": true,       
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/MoneyMachine/screen_analystEst.php",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Symbol", "sortable":true },
        { "data": "CompanyName" },
        { "data": "StockType" },
        { "data": "ExDivDate" },
        { "data": "Dividend" },
        { "data": "DivYield" },
        { "data": "DivFrequency" },
        { "data": "DivPayDate" },
        { "data": "PriceToNav" },
        { "data": "AppreciationPotential" }
    ]    
});
```

I've tried it with and without the "ordering" and "sortable" parameters but same result.  I've also tried various column definition parameters with no joy.  Suggestions?

Comment: What you are doing seems to be correct. Can you maybe provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you are using server side processing, the sorting happens in server side. Maybe you can check your screen_analystEst.php file if it processes the request correctly.

Comment: Ah, that was it.  I commented out serverSide parameter and then sorting worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ogreucha for suggesting to turn off server side processing.  I did that and now sorting works fine.  Here is the new code:

```
    $('#appPotTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": "/MoneyMachine/screen_analystEst.php",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Symbol" },
        { "data": "CompanyName" },
        { "data": "StockType" },
        { "data": "ExDivDate" },
        { "data": "Dividend" },
        { "data": "DivYield" },
        { "data": "DivFrequency" },
        { "data": "DivPayDate" },
        { "data": "PriceToNav" },
        { "data": "AppreciationPotential" }
    ]    
});
```